# Laravel socialite don't have permission to access this link on server

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-socialite

I'm trying to make social login using Google, Facebook, and LinkedIn on my website 
the last two works very well but Google always gives me error like this :

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /test/login/google/callback on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

I don't know why it's only appearing with Google, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for getting this error is because Google+ API is not enabled

go on google console account and enable Google+ API. If you haven't known how to enable Google+ services then follow this steps:

First Open your Google Console Account from Here: [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com/)

Then Go to -> library -> select Google+ API -> **Enable**

If you have any configuration related problem then see my GitHub code for [Socialite](https://github.com/udhavsarvaiya/Socialite)